# Is it possible to "limit" the width of a SignHere Tab?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have the following code that creates a [SignHere Tab](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Sign%20Here%20Tab.htm) at a specific location in my document page :

```
SignHere signHere = new SignHere
            {
                DocumentId = documentId,
                PageNumber = pageNumber,
                RecipientId = signer.RecipientId,
                ScaleValue = "0.6",
                XPosition = xPosition.ToString(),
                YPosition = yPosition.ToString()
            };
```

I also add to the right side of it the signature date :

```
DateSigned signatureDate = new DateSigned
            {
                Bold = bool.TrueString,
                DocumentId = documentId,
                PageNumber = pageNumber,
                RecipientId = signer.RecipientId,
                XPosition = (xPosition + 55).ToString(),
                YPosition = (yPosition + 25).ToString()
            };
```

However, if my signer has too long of a name, the signature overlaps with the date.
Is there a way to "limit" the actual size of the signature ?

[image]

Below is an example of a DocuSign competitor that shows how they dynamically adapt the signature to the Tab created for each document :
[image]

Comment: I think you will find my solution "creative" and that maybe your question was loaded with assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no parameter to limit the size of the adopted signature.

Comment: I disagree. The same issue is easily avoidable when you are doing a signature on paper as the signer has total control over the size of its own signature (except on a few instances)
Please see my updated question with the example of one of DocuSign competitor that actually dynamically resizes the signature to make sure it fits into the Tab created for each signature.

Comment: Why a negative vote, I answered your qs saying that that is not available in DocuSign. Paper can have issue if you have Data printed next to where signature is expected and there can be scenarios where your signature is too big to fit in the proper place

Comment: Correct, you answered my question but like I stated above, I disagree with your statement that this issue can exist when the signer is doing the signature on paper.

Comment: Edited my answer so that it responds to your qs only. I should not have added comments on my answer so that other can get benefit out of the response. No I think you can upvote it and accept it as answer as well.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I see several problems with this Question **"as is"** still and have made my points below (Love it @Amit K Bist and @Frederic) :

1. This was and still is a general question like Dev's find frustrating because it lacks specificity :-)
2. I would reword to "With a DocuSign Signature tab using the API is it possible to set a bounding box that the signature (Adopted or To be Adopted) will be resized to fit in that can be placed anywhere on the document canvas to be burnished to the final document while still being legible and zoomable"
3. The answer is No to my restated question at this time (product may be working on this, I can't say one way or another)
4. The answer is Yes to this question "Is it possible to “limit” the width of a SignHere Tab?
   " with a very narrowly scoped solution to address the way the question is phrased as I have proven with the attached [file - Sample Signed PDF](https://blog.grigsbyconsultingllc.com/please_docusign_test_pdf/) and image :-) Solution is to force the Signature tab to the bottom right of the document page canvas to force the burnishing process to trim the Signature size you can specify upper left x and y.

Gota love us developers and how we think out of the box. Below is an image of the bottom of page with signature "sized" and COC showing actual signature full width. Now clearly this is not the desired result when you want the date to the right, yet that was not the requirement as you can now easily see, or is it infinitely zoomable which will bring up the "value" of the signature if it is not legible, a major part of the value of signatures. So let's not forget why we collect signatures and make applications and forms that keep that desire prominent and protected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Why not do like the competitor example and dynamically resize the font of the signature text ?

Comment: Because Product Managers made a decision based on Requirements they had at the time based on what was important to customers I suspect :-) Please review this help link for an appropriate contact for your Product Feature Enhancement request. I know for a fact they listen to paying clients https://www.docusign.com/DocuSignHelp/DocuSignHelp.htm